How to prevent JWT token from being used on a different device in a React.js website?
I'm working on a React.js website where I'm using JWT tokens for authentication. The issue I'm facing is related to token security across different devices.
Current Setup:
Token Issuance: Tokens are issued by a Node.js backend using jsonwebtoken.
Token Storage: Tokens are stored in localStorage.
Authentication Library: I'm using react-token-auth to manage authentication and authorization in my React application.
Problem Description:
Token Behavior: When a JWT token is copied and pasted into another device, it continues to grant access, which I want to prevent.
Security Measures: I've implemented short-lived access tokens with a refresh token mechanism.
Server-Side Validation: Tokens are validated on the server-side to ensure they are legitimate and not expired.
Issue Details:
Despite the above measures, tokens copied to another device continue to work and grant access.
What did you try?
Short-Lived Tokens: Implemented short-lived access tokens along with a refresh token mechanism to manage session expiration.
Server-Side Validation: Validated tokens on the server-side to ensure they are legitimate and not expired.
LocalStorage Management: Stored tokens in localStorage using react-token-auth.
What were you expecting?
I expected that when a user copies a JWT token to another device:
The copied token should not grant access on the new device.
Access should only be granted on the original device where the token was issued.
However, despite these measures, the copied token continues to provide access on different devices.
